# flattening future of option after mapping with a function that return future of option

Tags: scala

I have a collection of type `Future[Option[String]]` and I map it to a function that returns `Future[Option[Profile]]`, but this create a return type of `Future[Option[Future[Option[Profile]]]]` because `queryProfile` return type is `Future[Option[Profile]]'

```
val users: Future[Option[User]] = someQuery
val email: Future[Option[String]] = users map(opSL => opSL map(_.email) )
val userProfile = email map {opE => opE map {E => queryProfile(E)}}
```

I need to use the `Profile` object contained deep inside `val userProfile` without unpacking all these levels, what would be the right way to use `flatMap` or `flatten', or is there a better approach all together ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get a "partial Future" with something like this:

```
  val maybeProfile: Future[Profile] = users
    .collect { case Some(u) => u.email }
    .flatMap { email => queryProfile(email) }
    .collect { case Some(p) => p }
```

Now `maybeProfile` contains the (completely "naked"/unwrapped) `Profile` instance, but only if it was able to find it. You can `.map` it as usual to do something else with it, that'll work in the usual ways.

If you want to ever block and wait for completion, you will have to handle the missing case at some point. For example:

```
   val optionalProfile: Option[Profile] = Await.result(
     maybeProfile
       .map { p => Some(p) } // Or just skip the last `collect` above
       .recover { case _:NoSuchElementException => None },
     1 seconds
   )
```

If you are happy with just having `Future[Option[Profile]]`, and would prefer to have the "unwrapping" magic, and handling the missing case localized in one place, you can put the two fragments from above together like this:

```
val maybeProfile: Future[Option[Profile]] = users 
  .collect { case Some(u) => u.email }
  .flatMap { email => queryProfile(email) }
  .recover { case _:NoSuchElementException => None }
```

Or use `Option.fold` like the other answer suggested:

```
val maybeProfile: Future[Option[Profile]] = users
    .map { _.map(_.email) }
    .flatMap { _.fold[Future[Option[Profile]]](Future.successful(None))(queryProfile) }
```

Personally, I find the last option less readable though.

Comment: for some reason it can't resolve the `u` in `collect { Some(u) => u.email }` and also complains that the actual type is `Any`

Comment: @BinaryA Sorry about that, fixed now (there was a `case` missing before `Some` for the compiler to realize you want it treated as a PartialFunction)

Comment: last solution using `Option.fold` is missing parenthesis `)` near the end  , additionally at `(queryProfile)` I get an error where expected is `(String)=>Future[None.Type]` but actual is `(String)=>Future[Option[Profile]]`

Comment: Indeed. Fixed. See what I meant, when I said I thought it was less readable? :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think a monad transformer such as OptionT provided by scalaz/cats would be the cleanest approach:

```
val users = OptionT[Future,User](someQuery)
def queryProfile(email:String) : OptionT[Future,Profile] = ...
for {
  u <- users
  p <- queryProfile(u.email)
} yield p
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just create a helper method like this:

```
private def resolveProfile(optEmail: Option[String]): Future[Option[Profile] =
  optEmail.fold(Future.successful(None)) { email =>
    queryProfile(email).map(Some(_))
  }
```

which then allows you to just `flatMap` your original `email` future like so:

```
val userProfile = email.flatMap(resolveProfile)
```